# Tensorflow softmax evaluation

Tags: python, tensorflow

Will both the snippets produce the same result in tensorflow?

```
graph =tf.get_default_graph()   

imgs = graph.get_tensor_by_name('Input:0')
logits = graph.get_tensor_by_name('Output/Conv:0')

for i in range(0,100):
            pred_val = sess.run(tf.contrib.layers.softmax(logits), feed_dict={imgs: arr})
            preds.append(pred_val)

pred = np.concatenate(preds)
```

And inserting the softmax at a different position like below:

```
imgs = graph.get_tensor_by_name('Input:0')
logits = graph.get_tensor_by_name('Output/Conv:0')
logits_sf = tf.contrib.layers.softmax(logits)
for i in range(0,100):
            pred_val = sess.run(logits_sf, feed_dict={imgs: arr})
            preds.append(pred_val)

pred = np.concatenate(preds)
```

Will both the outputs of the pred be different or the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Updated]** The new versions of code are identical in the functional sense: you will get the same `pred_val` on each iteration and, as a result, the same `preds`. But there's a catch in the second snippet and it's important. Each consecutive call of `tf.contrib.layers.softmax` creates a new node in the graph, even though it's used only once. If you print the graph definition, you'll see 100 `softmax` ops, while the first snippet will have just one. Another fun side effect: this node *will not* be present in tensorboard. Try to avoid creation of ops while training, because it's a sure way to consume all of your RAM and crash the process. In other words, the first snippet is better.

**[Original answer]** No, just because you've defined `logits_sf` node in the graph doesn't mean it will be executed in session. Your second code snippet evaluates only `logits`, which doesn't depend on the softmax op.

So the results will be different: the first one will produce the probability distribution in each `pred_val`, while the second one will produce raw logits.

Comment: Thanks!. Also when i used the snippet 1 on a GPU with 12GB memory, after calculating an image with a dim of (2(batch),640(h),480(w),13(class)) for almost after 4 such calculations i was facing a memory exhaustion issues, any reason why it could happen?

Comment: @AbishekVivek can you write another question? I think most of memory is used by the network and I'll need to look at the code